# Proper way to codesign swift framework included with distribution app

Tags: swift, xcode, code-signing

I have a enterprise app that is using some swift frameworks via podfile. I'm signing my app with the bundle id com.whatever.myapp using an enterprise distribution cert and provisioning profile. That's all fine.

But I'm getting errors when it tries to build the swift frameworks since the bundle id is different - for example org.cocoapods.Alamofire.

How should I be code signing my swift frameworks? Should this still be done with an enterprise distribution cert and provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

they will be automatically codeSign to with your app's target.
just recheck your bundle identifier in your app's target and rebuild it.